# <ul> - float li's - parent element width

Tags: html, css

I want to `float` `<li>` to the **left** in `ul ul` - without setting a `width` to the inner `<ul>` element 
The problem is that the `<ul>` is in a `nav` with `width:70px;` *(take a look at jsfiddle)*

Got the following ( http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/ )

CSS:

```
nav {
    width:70px;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    position:relative;
}

ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:70px;
    width:auto;
}

ul ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Test</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">sub2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If i set e.x. `ul ul { width:200px; }` it works, i also tried `width:auto` - but that doens't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the `position:relative` that you have set on your `<li>` in your css.

Delete this row in your css and it should be fine:

```
li { position:relative; }
```

Check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/3/)** to see its working.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/3/)**

---

**Update:** *(after new comment from OP)*

 You schould give the `ul ul` a `width` with fixed pixels.

```
ul ul {
    ....
    width:200px;      /* instead of width:auto; */
}
```

Check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/11/)** to see its working.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/11/)**

Comment: thanks! you also got a solution if i set the nav `position:fixed;` ? http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/10/

Comment: Check my update ;) i hope that you can set the width of the second `ul`

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately not :/ maybe i should set the width with js, but thats not so clean

Comment: True, than you will get inline-code.. instead of having it in a stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

C Travel's answer is correct, you need to remove `position: relative;` from your `li`

But if you can't do that for one reason or another, an alternative is to set `display: table;` on `ul ul`

[**<kbd>Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/6/)

Comment: You could use `display:table;` but still than, when you add more list items, it doesn't work. Check you example with more list items http://jsfiddle.net/qfemF/9/

Comment: no problem, still a solution to his problem, when having 2 list-items.